# Is there a way to have switch track longer than thumb?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have this output:

[image]

My issue is the **track longer** than the thumb.

I already have a thinner track but the thumb is at the end of the track:

[image]

[image]

Here is my XMLs:

My switch element customized in the layout:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/invite_member_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:switchMinWidth="55dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_background"
    android:track="@drawable/track_background" />
```

My `@drawable/thumb_background`. Just a selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_normal" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

My `@drawable/switch_thumb_checked`. Round element with my desired color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/violet_light" />
</shape>
```

My `@drawable/switch_thumb_normal`. Same as previously round element with my desired color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/pink_light" />
</shape>
```

My `@drawable/track_background`. The solution I found to have a thinner track:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/violet_light_50" />
    <size android:height="5dp" />
    <corners android:radius="40dp" />
    <!-- results in the track looking smaller than the thumb -->
    <stroke
        android:width="8dp"
        android:color="#00ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Please add code to your post. Depending on how you achieved your current output add java, kotlin or xml.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk sorry I missed to precise.... I just edited my message thanks for your help ! And to be precise, I am open to all solutions :) xml / java or kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Change code of `switch_thumb_checked` and `switch_thumb_normal` to

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
  <item>
      <shape android:shape="oval"
          >
          <padding android:top="5dp"
              android:left="5dp"
              android:right="5dp"
              android:bottom="5dp"/>
          <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
          <size android:width="30dp"
              android:height="30dp"/>
      </shape>
  </item>
    <item
        >

        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/violet_light"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: thanks for your help ! transparent was a good idea but this one is not working... the track takes the thumb size (30dp) and the violet / pink thumb is still a the start of the track...